How to map two nested list with Automapper
Entities
public class PurchaseReq
{
    ...
    public string PrNumber { get; set; } // primary key
    public List<PurchaseReqItem> PurchaseReqItems { get; init; } = [];
    public List<PurchaseReqCharge> PurchaseReqCharges { get; init; } = [];
}

public class PurchaseReqItem
{
    ...
    public int Id { get; init; } // primary key
    public string PrNumber { get; set; } // foreign key
    public PurchaseReq PurchaseReq { get; init; } //navigation property
}

public class PurchaseReqCharge
{
    ...
    public int Id { get; init; } // primary key
    public string PrNumber { get; set; } // foreign key
    public PurchaseReq PurchaseReq { get; init; } //navigation property
}

Dtos
public class PurchaseReqDto
{
    ...
    public string PrNumber { get; set; }
    public List<PurchaseReqItemDto> PurchaseReqItems { get; init; } = [];
    public List<PurchaseReqChargeDto> PurchaseReqCharges { get; init; } = [];
}

public class PurchaseReqItemDto
{
    ...
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string PrNumber { get; set; }
    public PurchaseReqDto PurchaseReq { get; init; }
}

public class PurchaseReqChargeDto
{
    ...
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string PrNumber { get; set; }
    public PurchaseReqDto PurchaseReq { get; init; }
}

Mapping profile
public class PurchaseReqProfile : Profile
{
    public PurchaseReqProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<PurchaseReq, PurchaseReqDto>();
        
        CreateMap<PurchaseReqDto, PurchaseReq>()
            .ForMember(d => d.PurchaseReqItems, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.PurchaseReqItems))
            .ForMember(d => d.PurchaseReqCharges, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.PurchaseReqCharges));
    }
}

public class PurchaseReqItemProfile : Profile
{
    public PurchaseReqItemProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<PurchaseReqItem, PurchaseReqItemDto>();
        
        CreateMap<PurchaseReqItemDto, PurchaseReqItem>()
            .ForMember(d => d.TaxRate, o => o.Ignore());
    }
}

public class PurchaseReqChargeProfile : Profile
{
    public PurchaseReqChargeProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<PurchaseReqCharge, PurchaseReqChargeDto>();
        
        CreateMap<PurchaseReqChargeDto, PurchaseReqCharge>()
            .ForMember(d => d.OtherCharge, o => o.Ignore());
    }
}

AutoMapper add to services in Program.cs
AutoMapper version 13.0.1
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
Data fetched by PurchaseReqRepo
public async Task<PurchaseReq> GetPrForUpdateAsync(string prNumber)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(prNumber);

        return await context.PurchaseReqs
            .Include(pr => pr.PurchaseReqItems)
            .Include(pr => pr.PurchaseReqCharges)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(pr => pr.PrNumber == prNumber);
    }

Update API
[HttpPut]
[CanUserUpdate(RolesConstant.PurchaseReq)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePurchaseReq([FromBody] PurchaseReqDto purchaseReqDto)
{
    if (!short.TryParse(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value,out var userId))
        return Unauthorized();
        
    var purchaseReq = await purchaseReqRepo.GetPrForUpdateAsync(purchaseReqDto.PrNumber);
    if (purchaseReq == null)
        return NotFound();
        
    if (purchaseReq.IsSubmitted)
        return BadRequest(string.Format($"PR ({purchaseReq.PrNumber}) was already submitted for approval and can't be updated."));
        
    mapper.Map(purchaseReqDto, purchaseReq, options => 
        options.BeforeMap((prDto, pr) =>
        {
            pr.RemoveUnMatchedItems(prDto.PurchaseReqItems);
            pr.RemoveUnMatchedCharges(prDto.PurchaseReqCharges);
        }));
        
    purchaseReq.UpdateBy(userId);
        
    await purchaseReqRepo.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}

When mapping purchaseReqDto to purchaseReq, I get error :

AutoMapper, System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity
type 'PurchaseReqCharge' cannot be tracked because another instance
with the key value '{Id: 3}' is already being tracked. When attaching
existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given
key value is attached.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

What does this code do?: purchaseReq.UpdateBy(userId);

public void UpdateBy(short userId)
{
LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
LastUserId = userId;
}
that's all it does.


I don't know what I am doing wrong here

EF performs data modification operations using tracking, when you fetch the data for update it is tracked, but AutoMapper during mapping will create completely new collection with new elements so when you will try to save the updated entity it will contain "duplicate" items (from EF change tracker point of view).
You can try looking into AutoMapper.Collection library. For example as a quick fix on mapper level something like the following should work:
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => cfg.AddCollectionMappers(), typeof(PurchaseReq));

And for all Dto -> Entity mappings:
CreateMap<PurchaseReqItemDto, PurchaseReqItem>()
    .EqualityComparison((dto, item) => item.Id == dto.Id);

From the docs:


If ID's match, then AutoMapper will map OrderDTO to Order
If OrderDTO exists and Order doesn't, then AutoMapper will add a new Order mapped from OrderDTO to the collection
If Order exists and OrderDTO doesn't, then AutoMapper will remove Order from collection


Also consider checking the docs - there is Automapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore which has a set of specific methods for managing such situations.
P.S.
In general I would argue that creating DTOs exactly matching your entities including the relationship cycles is not a very good idea.

I had previously tried Automapper.Collection but didnt get any luck. The last sentence about messy DTOs was the problem, after removing unwanted nesting it worked. Thank you. @Guru Stron
